# Using django channels with threading.Thead

Tags: django, python-multithreading, django-channels

I'm using django channels in order to send multiple responses to a single request. The code is something like this:

```
class terminal(WebsocketConsumer):
   def connect(self):
       self.accept()

   def disconnect(self, close_code):
       self.close()

   def receive(self, text_data):
       data_json = json.loads(text_data)
       if data_json['event'] == 'initial':
          self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data)
          self.t.daemon = True
          self.t.start()
       elif data_json['event'] == 'pause':
          pass
       print("done")

   def send_data(self):
       n = 100
       end = 1000000
       while (n + 1 < end)
          # some code
          self.send(json.dumps({'data':data})
          n += 1
```

I've used thread to be able to listen to ***pause*** and other events while data is being sent to the client. 
The problem is that the thread keeps running after websocket gets disconnected.

Is there a way to kill a python thread in ***disconnect*** function? Or maybe a better way to implement this?

Comment: killing python threads is not easy, if your thread has a while tool what you can do is set some flag that the thread checks on each iteration round the run loop. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

Comment: i would suggest instread of opeing a thread you create a child async runloop. this can be killed more cleanly and will play with the rest of the async nature of channels better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to solve your problem. I would suggest, you use the function  `sync_to_async()` from `asgiref.sync`. It creates a new thread and "awaits", until it is finished. "awaits" means, that in an async context, other code can run in the meantime.

To call `sync_to_async()` you have to use a `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`

```
class terminal(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
   async def connect(self):
       awaitself.accept()

   async def disconnect(self, close_code):
       await self.close()

   async def receive(self, text_data):
       data_json = json.loads(text_data)
       if data_json['event'] == 'initial':
          await sync_to_async(self.send_data)()
       elif data_json['event'] == 'pause':
          pass
       print("done")

   def send_data(self):
       n = 100
       end = 1000000
       while (n + 1 < end)
          # some code
          sync_to_async(self.send)(json.dumps({'data':data})
          n += 1
```